# Creating a custom action on text link

Tags: android, text, hyperlink, action

This is seems like a pretty simple question, but I'm not sure if there's a solution to it. Is it possible to set a custom action for a text link (those blue texts that are underlined) inside a TextView? In other words, is it possible to have a handler do something on an event like onClick on the link?

Comment: Are you talking about HTML in a webView? Or a TextView with AutoLink?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm talking about a TextView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the link in the text, and use the `autoLink` attribute for it. It will use the marked text as link. Otherwise, the only option is to use an `OnClickListener` as suggested by nicholas.

You can look at the `autoLink` attribute doc here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:autoLink

If your text is: "You will find it at http://www.example.com", and you set `android:autoLink="web"`, then the link will be highlighted and a browser will start after clicking it.

Comment: Well I'm going to assume that there's no way of doing something where you click "http://www.example.com" and set an onClickListener for that link to do something else that's not a link to a webpage (maybe do a toast or open a dialog).

Comment: @AeroDroid not to my knowledge using the public API. You can always see how TextView was implemented and do something different in your own custom View.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this situation too, where I have `autolink` set up in TextViews to automatically handle URLs in TextViews. However, the default behavior is to open the web page in an external browser, so how do we make it open in an in-app browser (for example)?

Underneath the hood, this is handled for TextView by [LinkMovementMethod](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/method/LinkMovementMethod.java). Hence, the suggestion (by one of the answers) to customize onClickListener() of the TextView is not ideal, as it would involve reimplementing much of what LinkMovementMethod handles, so that it could precisely handle clicks/taps on what are identified as URLs.

More recently (years after this post was made), someone has come up with an enhancement over LinkMovementMethod, known as (what else?) [BetterLinkMovementMethod](https://github.com/saket/Better-Link-Movement-Method), described in more detail [this blog post](https://medium.com/@Saketme/a-better-way-to-handle-links-in-textview-27bb70b2d31c). I can confirm that it did work for me. With just a few lines of code changes, the TextView `autolinks` now open in the in-app browser (and clearly, all kinds of other behaviors can be customized as desired). I have no affiliation with BetterLinkMovementMethod or its creators, but am just a grateful user.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with an `EditText` or a `TextView`, they both have an [setOnClickListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29) method which you could override.

If you are working with a `WebView`, and the content created is yours, you can use JavaScript to handle click's of links.

If you are working with a `WebView` and the content you are viewing is not yours, I am not sure if there is a way to intercept those, but you should still be able to call setOnClickListener() on a WebView, as setOnClickListener() is defined in the View class.  I am just not sure how you would tell whether or not a link was clicked in that WebView...

Comment: Well I don't want the whole TextView to be linked. I want a piece of text inside the TextView to be the link and click that link will launch a custom action. For example, if the TextView had "Click HERE for something.", with "HERE" being the link, clicking that link would open a dialog window.

Comment: This could still be done with the onClickListener() as the click should report the coordinates of its hit.  Of course this would require you to do some math to determine which word was hit...